# MySQL Left Join Query not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The `history table` contains dates that I'm trying to match against the `participation table`. If the date doesn't exist in the `participation table`, then I want the record(s) pulled out so I can enter the participation data . But what I have doesn't work. Here's a rundown of what I'm using:

```
MariaDB [sotp]> describe history;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| historyid    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| amount       | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subsidy      | char(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_payment | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount_paid  | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| balance      | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| attend       | char(1)          | NO   |     | N       |                |
| atend_date   | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| groupid      | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clientid     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| memberid     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [sotp]> select clientid, attend_date
-> from history
-> where memberid = "1"
-> AND MONTH(attend_date) = "10"
-> AND YEAR(attend_date) = "2016"
-> AND attend_date <> "0000-00-00"
-> ORDER BY attend_date ASC;
+----------+-------------+
| clientid | attend_date |
+----------+-------------+
|        3 | 2016-10-11  |
|        1 | 2016-10-11  |
|        7 | 2016-10-11  |
|        2 | 2016-10-11  |
|        4 | 2016-10-11  |
|        5 | 2016-10-11  |
|        8 | 2016-10-11  |
|        9 | 2016-10-11  |
+----------+-------------+

MariaDB [sotp]> describe participation;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| partid    | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| notes     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| groupdate | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clientid  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| memberid  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [sotp]> select clientid, groupdate
-> from participation
-> where memberid = "1"
-> AND MONTH(groupdate) = "10"
-> AND YEAR(groupdate) = "2016"
-> AND groupdate <> "0000-00-00"
-> ORDER BY groupdate ASC;
+----------+------------+
| clientid | groupdate  |
+----------+------------+
|        2 | 2016-10-11 |
|        4 | 2016-10-11 |
+----------+------------+
```

And my `left join` query:

```
SELECT historyid, p.groupdate, h.attend_date, h.clientid, h.memberid
FROM history AS h
LEFT JOIN  participation AS p  ON p.groupdate = h.attend_date
WHERE h.memberid = "1"
AND MONTH(h.attend_date) = "10"
AND YEAR(h.attend_date) = "2016"
AND h.attend_date <> "0000-00-00"
ORDER BY h.attend_date ASC;
+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| historyid | groupdate  | attend_date | clientid | memberid |
+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+----------+
|        58 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        3 |        1 |
|        61 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        2 |        1 |
|        59 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        1 |        1 |
|        62 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        4 |        1 |
|        60 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        7 |        1 |
|        63 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        5 |        1 |
|        61 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        2 |        1 |
|        64 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        8 |        1 |
|        62 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        4 |        1 |
|        65 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        9 |        1 |
|        63 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        5 |        1 |
|        64 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        8 |        1 |
|        65 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        9 |        1 |
|        58 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        3 |        1 |
|        59 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        1 |        1 |
|        60 | 2016-10-11 | 2016-10-11  |        7 |        1 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

The `groupdate` field should be `NULL` except for `memberid` 2 and 4. Plus it gives the data twice. What am I doing wrong?

Best regards.

**UPDATE**

Per the request of `kasparg`:

```
MariaDB [sotp]> select *
-> from participation;
+--------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
| partid | notes                                         | groupdate  | clientid | memberid |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
|    824 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz | 2016-01-26 |        3 |        1 |
|    825 | lol hahaha and stuff                          | 2016-01-26 |        4 |        1 |
|    826 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa                        | 2016-01-26 |        2 |        1 |
|    827 | zzzzzzzzzzzzzzaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa              | 2016-01-26 |        1 |        1 |
|    828 | llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll          | 2016-01-28 |        3 |        1 |
|    829 | bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb                           | 2016-01-28 |        1 |        1 |
|    830 | Absent                                        | 2016-01-28 |        4 |        1 |
|    831 | Absent                                        | 2016-01-28 |        2 |        1 |
|    832 | llllkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk           | 2016-01-29 |        5 |        1 |
|    833 | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz             | 2016-01-29 |        4 |        1 |
|    834 | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                      | 2016-01-29 |        2 |        1 |
|    835 | ccccccccccccccccccccccc                       | 2016-01-29 |        1 |        1 |
|    836 | llllkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk           | 2016-01-29 |        3 |        1 |
|   1063 | zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz                  | 2016-01-30 |        3 |        1 |
|   1064 | ddddddddddddddddddddddddd                     | 2016-01-30 |        1 |        1 |
|   1065 | No entry made.                                | 2016-01-30 |        4 |        1 |
|   1066 | No entry made.                                | 2016-01-30 |        2 |        1 |
|   1075 | 2016-02-26: car wreck                         | 2016-10-11 |        2 |        1 |
|   1076 | 2016-02-26: broken legs                       | 2016-10-11 |        4 |        1 |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

**UPDATE**

```
MariaDB [sotp]> SELECT historyid, p.groupdate,  h.attend_date, p.clientid, h.clientid, h.memberid
-> FROM history AS h
-> LEFT JOIN  participation AS p  ON p.groupdate = h.attend_date and p.clientid = h.clientid
-> WHERE h.memberid = "1"
-> AND h.clientid = "1"
-> AND MONTH(h.attend_date) = "10"
-> AND YEAR(h.attend_date) = "2016"
-> AND h.attend_date <> "0000-00-00"
-> AND p.groupdate = "NULL"
-> ORDER BY h.attend_date ASC;
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I hard-coded `h.clientid = "1"` and still get nothing. And that record should return a `NULL` value for `groupdate`.

Comment: can you show what is inside participation table? SELECT * FROM participation limit 10;

Comment: I was having the same problem with mariadb. I found that doing two subqueries was the only way of getting the data the way I wanted, afaik this wasn't necesary with mysql.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58173579/4227722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get records where participation date is missing. Add an additional criteria to the WHERE clause: `AND p.groupdate IS NULL`

Also, note that you are joining participation only on groupdate, join it also on clientid, like this: `LEFT JOIN  participation AS p  ON p.groupdate = h.attend_date and p.clientid = h.clientid`

Comment: You're assessment of my query is correct. Please see my update. What you showed me looks right. All of the query looks right...to me. But it fails every time.

Comment: Sorry. I made the changes in the changes to the `php` page and it still doesn't pull out the `NULL` records. This is puzzling, to say the least.

Comment: In your posted data, you filter on p.memberid =1, but not in your query. It may affect your results.

Comment: @AmelieTurgeon - The memberid is stored in both tables alongside the clientid for the clients. Please keep in mind that I've hard-coded `memberid = "1"` and `clientid = "1"` for example purposes. The production queries obviously use variables. That said, I'll throw out what I have and start anew. I see no other way to go. The last UPDATE in my Post, that query should yield a record result, but it doesn't. And that's what has me puzzled. So crazy!

Comment: @Landslyde then don't forget to join on clientid and memberid as well as the date. And if it still doesn't work, select for exploration purpose p.* and h.*. You may understand what goes wrong.

Comment: @AmelieTurgeon - I actually reworked everything and have it running smoothly now. Thank you for your input though. I appreciate you for that. By the way, and I didn't mention this, this particular query is for posting the same `notes` to all the clients at once...a mass posting. That's why I wasn't using the `clientid`.